# Strange Recycler View Bind Holder throwing Null pointer Exception

Tags: android, adapter, android-5.0-lollipop, android-recyclerview

I implemented recycler view successfully in my app but now I noticed some time it throws this Nullpointer exception below is the crash log

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.example.project.CustomRecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(CustomRecyclerAdapter.java:83)
at com.example.project.CustomRecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(CustomRecyclerAdapter.java:26)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:4048)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:3366)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:3258)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1803)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1302)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1265)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:522)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:1918)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:2155)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14061)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4374)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1655)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1513)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1426)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14061)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4374)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14061)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4374)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14061)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4374)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14061)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4374)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1986)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1807)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4454)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4895)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

CustomRecyclerAdapter Line no 83

```
viewHolder.textView.setText(getTitle(position));
```

CustomRecyclerAdapter Line no 26

```
private final int orientation;
```

Do you guys have any idea why i am getting this?

View Holder

```
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

   public ImageView imageView;
   public TextView time;
   public TextView textView;
   public TextView temperature;

   public ViewHolder(View row){
       super(row);
       imageView = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
       time = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.time);
       textView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView);
       temperature = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.temperature);
   }
}
```

Comment: Show your viewHolder and the getTitle

Comment: check now i added view holder and getTitle never return null.

Comment: sorry late reply, do you think it would have some issue, because i don't have any steps to reproduce that crash.

Comment: My first guess is that this happens after orientation changed. `itemView` of holder is null at this point, hence NPE.

Comment: But then it would happen for very first itemView not for last second.

Comment: Lines do not match, `private final int orientation;` cannot be line 26. Can you share the full adapter code?

Comment: it is line 26 thats why i don't know why i am getting this exception and major problem is 'I am not getting this exception consistently'

Comment: Did you find the cause? I'm receiving similar crash reports from Android 4.1 devices only.

Comment: not sure but i am having two different layout one for portrait and other for landscape, in landscape i am missing one linear layout as expected which is causing that exception

Comment: I do not have a solution unfortunately, but this happened to me the other day and I cannot understand why. For me it happened when I updated the app from Google Play (alpha version) and opened it from there and then I immediately got the same crash. After re-opening the app everything was back to normal and I cannot reproduce it.